# Swift 2: find the location of the first byte of a sequence

Tags: swift2

In NSData object I need to find the location of the first byte of a specific bytes sequence "D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1". How may I do it in Swift 2?

Comment: Will you please elaborate it with an example? Are you saying you want the location of D0 or the whole written string "D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1". in some other thing. If possible try stating what you tried.

Comment: I need to locate the whole string. I can create an array from raw data and then to make a loop to indentitfy the string but I hope that exist a function that is able to resolve the problem quickly.

Comment: Do you want first match or  all matches . try using functional programming methods (filter, map and reduce kind of methods) they are a great help for this kind of thing .Try to search for the first word in the string , when found proceed ahead .